# How to do 2+ rotations while resetting the origin between each during a keyframe?

Tags: html, css, rotation, css-animations, keyframe

I try to do an animated box that will unfold itself on the page load.

I have a panel lifted up. I try to rotate it 90deg to the ground, and after, I would want to lift it up again based on the other edge 90deg.

I tried to change the origin (transform-origin: top) but it change the origin to the original origin. I had to add 2 translation to position it at the right place but it create a bump. The edge on the ground don't stick on the ground.

Here's my current fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hbnta1uj/2/

I also tried without modifying the origin but I still get a bump:

```
@keyframes slideFront2 {
    0% {
        transform: rotateX(-0deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateX(-180deg) translateZ(-100px) translateY(100px);
    }
}
```

I have another idea where I position the second panel flat already and I hide it (opacity 0) and at 50% when the first panel is flat I show the second and just 90deg it.

But I would want to know for more complex animations if there's a way to do it the way I describe it, by always start at the new position the new transformation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would consider an animation on the container to make it easier where you only need one keyframe:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: rgb(194, 194, 194);
}

.progressbar-wrapper {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  top: calc(50% - 50px);
  left: calc(50% - 150px);
  position: absolute;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(-30deg);
}

.progressbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform-origin: bottom;
  animation: 0.5s ease-out 1 slideFront forwards;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.side {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(254, 254, 254, 0.3);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

@keyframes slideFront {
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(-90deg);
  }
}

.bottom {
  box-shadow: 10px 10px 50px 5px rgba(90, 90, 90, 0.7);
}

.back {
  animation: 1s ease-out 0.5s 1 slideFront forwards;
  transform-origin: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="progressbar-wrapper">
    <div class="progressbar">
      <div class="side back">
      </div>
      <div class="side bottom">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing I discover is that the order matter in the translate function. Everything is executed left to right so the origin of the rotation will be relative to the current position of the element if you execute everything left to right (Here's 2 boxes getting the same rotation translation but the order differ: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oOQGPp)

So in my example, if you do:

```
    50.001% {
        transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(00px) translatey(100px) ;
        transition-timing-function: linear;
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateX(0deg) translateZ(100px) translatey(00px) ;
        transition-timing-function: linear;
    }
```

The rotation will be applied before the translation so the rotation origin will not be the bottom line after the translation but it will be the position without the origin based on the translated part (So it will be the 0% position origin.) CSS will fail to make the path of the animation and it will add a little bump.

But if you do `transform: TRANSLATE ROTATE`, the rotation will be applied after the translation so the origin of the rotation will be related to the position with the translation. This is how I was able to rotate the item without getting the little bump bug.

Here's the full fixed css. You can run it in my original jsfiddle to see the result

```
* {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
    width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    height: 100vh;
    background-color: rgb(194, 194, 194);
}
.progressbar-wrapper {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.progressbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform: rotateX(-20deg) rotateY(-30deg);
}

.side {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(254, 254, 254, 0.3);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

@keyframes slideBottom {
    0% {
        transform: rotateX(-0deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    }
}
@keyframes slideFront {
    0% {
        transform: rotateX(-0deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotateX(-90deg);
    }
    50.001% {
        transform: translateZ(100px) rotateX(90deg);
        transition-timing-function: linear;
    }
    100% {
        transform: translateZ(100px) rotateX(0deg) ;
        transition-timing-function: linear;
    }
}

.bottom {
    animation: 0.5s ease-out 0s 1 slideBottom forwards;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 50px 5px rgba(90, 90, 90, 0.7);
    transform-origin: bottom;
}

.back {
    animation: 1s ease-out 0s 1 slideFront forwards;
    transform-origin: bottom;
}
```